# How to disable autoconf feature of IPv6 usinf interfaces file?

Tags: embedded, ipv6

I am using linux 3.2.0. I want to disable autoconf feature of IPv6. For that I have added following lines in /etc/network/interfaces file.

```
iface inet6 eth0 static
address <IPv6_address>
netmask 64
autoconf 0
```

After this I used "ifdown eth0" and "ifup eth0". Still I am getting IPv6 global address based on MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

The order of parameters on your `iface` line is wrong. It is configuring interface `inet6` for the `eth0` protocol. It should be:

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
    address <IPv6_address>
    netmask 64
```

The `autoconf 0` bit is default for static configuration so you don't need to specify that.